# unified view to slightly different structs

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a complicated structs that evolved from version to version, adding/removing fields. For backward compatibility, all the versions are kept in the code, leading to something like this :

```
struct MyDataV0{
    int a;
    .....
};
struct MyDataV1{
    //int a disappeared for this version
    double d; //this fields was added to this version
    .....
};
```

I want to provide a unified view of this struct that is version agnostic. Is there a pattern or best practices to do this?

Comment: Add a common base class, and put a version enum member into the base class. Then you can store the base class's pointer.

Comment: By unified view, you mean you want to refer to them by the same name?

Comment: I'm surprised that fields are disappearing in latter versions.

Comment: @Mansoor In a naive version the user would do : `view=MyView(data)` where `data` is any version of the original struct, and then the `MyView` constructor will read it and provide a unique API. We can imagine that `MyView` struct contains the union of all the fields in different versions. I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution @Paul Fields disappear as we want to keep the struct small. Keeping the struct as small as possible is very important for our use case.

Comment: If "Keeping the struct as small as possible" is considered, any indirection layer might increase a struct's size. "ASAP" and "Unified view", which concern has higher priority in your context?

Comment: @volatile in that case, you should use namespaces to control the different version of your struct, with the current version in an inline namespace. Then you can overload any functions that uses your struct for all possible versions of the struct.

Comment: Polymorphism is an idea that one piece of code can work with different data structures. In C++ polymorphism can be achieved with virtual functions and templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a closer look at creating a flexible container, for example, in C++ 17 you can use `std::map` with `std::variant` values.
Its definition is unified and version-agnostic.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, double, std::string>> st;

    st["version"] = 2;
    st["field_int_v1"] = 1;
    st["field_double_v2"] = 1.1;  // added in version 2
    st["field_string_v2"] = "1.1 in text";

    //..
    // process somewhere
    std::cout << std::get<int>(st["field_int_v1"] ) << std::endl;
    if (std::get<int>(st["version"]) == 2){
        std::cout << std::get<double>(st["field_double_v2"] ) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::get<std::string>(st["field_string_v2"]) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not provide a 'unified view', the typical approach to handling multiple versions is with namespacing:

```
namespace my_data
{
    namespace v1
    {
        // v1
        struct MyData { … };
    }
    inline namespace v2
    {
        // v2
        struct MyData { … };
    }
}

// To use v2
my_data::MyData data = {};
// or
my_data::v2::MyData data1 = {};

// To use v1
my_data::v1::MyData data2 = {};
```

By default, you will use the version of the struct which is in the inline namespace, if you want to reference an older (possibly deprecated) version, you will have to be explicit. You can then overload any function which consumes `MyData`, in the same namespace as the struct and rely on [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) to find the correct overload.